# How to enable image transparency option on blender 2.9

Tags: 3d-view

I am currently trying to do some modeling using reference images, and I found out that in my current blender install (2.90.1) for some reason the image transparency does not work.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to BSE. Could you add a full screen screenshot to help us understand your question?

Answer (score 3):

I tested this in 2.90.0. After creating a reference image, you want it to still be selected, and then look in the *Object Data* tab of the Properties Panel, where there should be a **Transparency** section with a checkbox, which is off by default. Check the box to activate the option, and then move the associated slider.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Go to image settings there you find an option called 'Transparent'. Enable it.